# My model looks weird

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I was just doing my usual stuff, but when I checked back on part of the model, it looked like this:
[image]

I also pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd>, but it didn't fix anything.

Edit: The one one on the left is what I want. I exported the model a few days ago. [image]

Comment: This could be due to several reasons of which we can only guess since we do not have a blend-file to debug with... It could simply be flat surfaces set to smooth for the whole mesh...

Comment: Is there any way to turn a blend1 file into a blender file?

Comment: Yes, just rename it to .blend in your computer's file explorer/browser.

Comment: I did that before, but when i come back, the model looks like a circle of randomness

Comment: Do you think importing the model to a new blender file will work?

Comment: The .blend1 file is a previously saved, old file. If you save your blend file then Blender renames the existing, old *.blend file to *.blend1 and saves the new, current state, to *.blend. That way you can recover your last saved state if you accidentally saved the file.

Answer (score 1):

I can give better advice if you specify what you expect it to look like. It appears to me that you want to fix the smoothing groups. Depending on what you want, you can check out [Auto Smoothing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnU0TsNc3qo&t=43s): and alternatively how to use the [weighted normals modifier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUlRZPoB2NI)
Another thing I noticed is that you have auto keying on(blue dot on line editor) toggle this off so it isn't highlighted in blue and remove animation from all objects in the scene. If you forget this is on, objects can end up in unwanted locations and be confusing.